# RTBkit TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, zeromq, apache-zookeeper, rtbkit

I am trying to run RTBKit from Ubuntu 12.04lts with 4GB RAM.

I am following the steps from [**HERE**](https://github.com/rtbkit/rtbkit-preview/wiki/Getting%20Started)

I was able to execute steps before **sudo make -k all**.

But when I execute the command **sudo make -k all**, after some time it gives the error -

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects:
  File "/home/eywa/platform-deps/mongo-cxx-driver/SConstruct", line 71:
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-L" + os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"),
make: *** [install_mongodb_cxx_driver] Error 2
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
```

I am very new to RTBkit, Zookeeper. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but it looks like you're missing environment variables. Specifically, it seems like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set so sourcing your [.profile](https://github.com/rtbkit/rtbkit/wiki/Getting-Started#environment-variables) should fix your problem. You can validate with the following command `env | grep 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'` which should have the `~/local/lib` path.

Comment: I appreciate your help,but this project is now kicked off